# Argument Type is not assignable to parameter type Node JS Project Warning

Tags: node.js, typescript

When I run this code in WebStorm it gives me a warning:

`Argument type {where: {email: userData.emil}} is not assignable to parameter type NonNullFindOptions<Model["_attributes"]>`

What is that?

This is Node.js, Express & Sequelize based project.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Any ideas ? please

Answer (score 0):

User,findOne({where:{email.userDate.email}}, rejectOnEmpty: true).then....

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).